# How to host laravel applications in sub domains

Tags: laravel, subdomain, hosting, cpanel

I am hosting the laravel application first time in sub domain.

Here is my sub domain which I created and set document root path.

Image :
[image]

Here is my root folder image :

[image]

When I visit the created domain :

http://demo.myproject.com/

It returns an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/--/public_html/myrpoject/public/index.php on line 52

Index.php file

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class); // line no:52
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Is there something missing ?

Comment: It seems to me that this has nothing to do with your subdomain. What php version are you using on the server?

Comment: @Jerodev PHP version 7.2

Comment: @Javed You should create a `phpinfo.php` file into the subdomain public folder and then check the php version. Like add  `<?php
phpinfo();` lines into the `phpinfo.php`.
And check `http://demo.myproject.com/phpinfo.php`

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya it is showing old version of php. I will be back after updating the php version.will let you know.thanx.

Comment: @Javed After update PHP version it will be working for sure.